# How to handle unpredictable routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, content-management-system

Assume the following paths to be legitimate and resolving:

```
http://test.local/wizards/home
http://test.local/wizards/wizardfest2012/dates
http://test.local/dragons/
http://test.local/dragons/blog/stop-slaying-us
http://test.local/
```

This is (if you couldn't tell) for a CMS that includes a blog, so the slugs would be generated by the user. I have some routes to process first for reserved namespaces (admin, for example).

I assume that the user generated routes need to be routed to a `Page` controller - but, I don't think pragmatically adding a line to routes.rb is efficient. My question then, is how do I process the first part of the params (in this case, `wizards` and `dragons`) to get the correct information from the model?

Here's one of my ideas - split (somehow) the first part of the slug (again, `wizards` and `dragons` and pass the rest of the slug (for example, `/wizardfest2012/dates`) to the model to fetch the associated content.

Any thoughts on the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: What kind of CMS has different models for different pages? It's all the same model. Maybe if you post a less contrived example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Page controller, page model. Not sure where different models came from.

Comment: From your own words about splitting dragons/wizards off "the the model".

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether I understand what you want to achieve, but maybe this is what you want:

```
constraints :camp => /wizards|dragons/ do
  match ':camp/home'    => "pages#home"
  match ':camp/blog/:title' => "pages#blog"
  # ...and all the routes with known components
  match ':camp/*other'  => "pages#other"
end
```

You may create a `before_filter` which will recognize the `params[:camp]` and prepare the necessary models or whatever is needed.

The `other` action will receive the string `"wizardfest2012/dates"` as `params[:other]`. I hope that it was what you needed.

The ["Rails Routing from the Outside In"](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) guide may be worth reading, unless you have already read it.